Interface/Receiver Type Checking and Implicit Conversion in Golang
Modified from https://go.dev/tour/methods/9
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

func main() {
    var a Abser
    f := MyFloat(-math.Sqrt2)
    v := Vertex{3, 4}

    a = f  // a MyFloat implements Abser
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)\n", a, a)
    a = &v // a *Vertex implements Abser
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)\n", a, a)

    // In the following line, v is a Vertex (not *Vertex)
    // and does NOT implement Abser.
    //a = v
    
    // However, below is allowed. 
    // Why is *MyFloat an Abser? *MyFloat "does NOT implement Abser" either.
    a = &f
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)\n", a, a)

    fmt.Println(a.Abs())
}

type MyFloat float64

func (f MyFloat) Abs() float64 {
    if f < 0 {
        return float64(-f)
    }
    return float64(f)
}

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}


Outputs:
(-1.4142135623730951, main.MyFloat)
(&{3 4}, *main.Vertex)
(0xc00009a040, *main.MyFloat)
1.4142135623730951

Program exited.

Questions

Why is *MyFloat an Abser? *MyFloat "does NOT implement Abser" either.
Is any implicit conversion happening when a.Abs() is called? At compile time or run time?
Regarding explicit/implicit conversions, https://go.dev/tour/basics/13 says Unlike in C, in Go assignment between items of different type requires an explicit conversion. However, aren't https://go.dev/tour/methods/6 and https://go.dev/tour/methods/7 showing 2-way implicit type conversions between value and pointer types when used with receivers? But with functions, explicit conversions are needed?


The method set of a type determines which Interfaces it implements. The method set of *MyFloat includes all methods with receiver MyFloat.

Tip for future questions, if you are asking multiple questions (which will be closed as “too broad”) it probably means you haven’t yet figured out what exactly it is you’re asking. [ask]
